# Automatically highlight all occurrences of the selected text in visual mode

Tags: highlight

In text editors like sublime text, atom and notepad++, when you select a word, all matches are highlighted automatically as shown in the following screenshot of my atom editor:

[image: Automatically highlight the word permutation when selected]

I use `v` and select text in vim but how can I obtain all highlight functionality?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551231/highlight-variable-under-cursor-in-vim-like-in-netbeans and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227281/how-to-auto-highlight-the-current-word-in-vim

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## TL;DR: Combine `*` and `#` with `hlsearch`

You *could* highlight by using `match` and `<cword>` via an `autocommand` on an event like `CursorHold`. But I’m going to show an alternative method.

- `*` searches forward for the word under the cursor
- `#` searches backward for the word under the cursor

Both have variants (`g*`, `g#`) that don’t restrict the searches to word-boundaries.

Use `n` and `N` to navigate.

By `set`ting `hlsearch`, these searches will also highlight matches.

### Why do this?

1. It uses a vim search instead of arbitrary highlights, so you can actually navigate between matches
2. It uses existing vim machinery and needs little-to-no setup
3. The commands are good to learn anyway (and then you start to like `gd`, among others)

### Disadvantage

This is does not work for “partial words”: if you visually-select part of a word and hit `*`, you won’t get the result you want.

One workaround is one of the many visual star plugins.

Another is to simply yank `y` and then search `/<C-r>"<CR>` (vim notation: type slash `/` to search, then Control-R quote to paste the selected text, then hit enter).

Comment: Why vim does has to be so hard? I hope all these learning commands and losing some features from other editors will be worth it.

Comment: @AbhishekAgrawal I dont see it as losing a feature—fwiw, i dont feel like im missing anything. As far as worth it, any adjustment to workflow comes with cost. Switching to vim years ago paid off for me.

Comment: @as2d3 Totally worth it. Plus once you figure out the key combo to do exactly what you want like the answer describe, you can make a binding for it. For example in my case, I select text (any text, doesn't matter what characters) and when I hit `<enter>` it highlights all matches (with hlsearch) and `n` and `p` go to them.

Answer (score 6):

D. Ben Knoble's answer provides the correct features to look into. Here's a solution that takes that knowledge and gives you some easy key mappings.

First, here's how regular `*` works with `hlsearch` enabled (see Ben Knoble's answer for that):

[image]

Now the new feature that we will create will do the following. In the next recording, we select some text with VISUAL mode, then hit the `enter` key and it will highlight all matches, like so:

[image]

It is also useful for selecting whole lines and finding matching lines! In the next recording I pressed capital `V` (shift+v) to enter VISUAL LINE mode and select the current line, then I hit the enter key, and it highlighted all three identical lines:

[image]

Nifty!

Note, because this hooks into vim's built-in search feature, you can use `n` and `p` to navigate to the next/previous matches just like with `*` or `#` search.

To have this functionality, add this mapping to your `.vimrc` (or `init.vim` in neovim):

```
" highlight the visual selection after pressing enter.
xnoremap <silent> <cr> "*y:silent! let searchTerm = '\V'.substitute(escape(@*, '\/'), "\n", '\\n', "g") <bar> let @/ = searchTerm <bar> echo '/'.@/ <bar> call histadd("search", searchTerm) <bar> set hls<cr>
```

When you have text selected, this mapping will programmatically add the selected text as the last thing you search for (same as if you had used the `/` key and inputted in manually).

If you have `hlsearch` enabled, the new search text will be highlighted.

### Bonus #1!

I like to toggle the search highlight, so I made ctrl+c toggle it in NORMAL mode (otherwise ctrl+c does not do anything in NORMAL mode, so now ctrl+c will be useful).

When I press ctrl+c repeatedly, it toggles `hlsearch`:

[image]

The mapping for that is:

```
" Give ctrl+c a job when it is otherwise being wasted!
" Now it toggles `hlsearch` while in NORMAL mode:
nnoremap <silent> <c-c> :if (&hlsearch == 1) \| set nohlsearch \| else \| set hlsearch \| endif<cr>
```

### Bonus #2!

The `*` and `#` will move your cursor, which you may not like. A lot of the time I would like to see matches, but without the cursor moving. So I mapped the `<enter>` key in NORMAL mode to search for the current word (very much like `*`) but without the cursor jumping.

This is what it looks like when I move to a word, and hit the enter key:

[image]

Notice the cursor stayed where it was! In my example, the `on` instances are close to each other, but if they were far apart, it could be annoying if the whole screen jumped to a new location when I didn't want it to.

And here's the mapping!

```
" Put <enter> to work too! Otherwise <enter> moves to the next line, which we can
" already do by pressing the <j> key, which is a waste of keys!
" Be useful <enter> key!:
nnoremap <silent> <cr> :let searchTerm = '\v<'.expand("<cword>").'>' <bar> let @/ = searchTerm <bar> echo '/'.@/ <bar> call histadd("search", searchTerm) <bar> set hls<cr>
```

### Bonus #3!

You can run Neovim inside VS Code with the [`Neo Vim`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=asvetliakov.vscode-neovim) extension. This runs neovim in the background, and you can use the above features right inside VS Code, and also take advantage of all of VS Code's other GUI features.

For example, in the next recording, I selected a line with capital `V`, and highlighted the matching identical lines with `enter`, and finally navigated to them with `n`:

[image]

Notice the VS Code GUI including the minimap! With VS Code you'll also have the nice intellisense tooltips with markdown rendering, git GUI, and everything else (many extensions).

Ironically, also notice VS Code's own highlighting (in blue) of the word that is under the cursor! That feature is the whole reason this StackOverflow exists! But now you can do even more with it than just visual matches (navigate to them, and more than just words).

### Takeaway

Vim and Neovim are really powerful once you learn them, and especially learn how to script them. They can do so much more with scripting. (And even more with VS Code features in the mix!).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nice answer. Two nits: why use the clipboard register when the unnamed or even the search register will do ? And your control c mapping is just `set hlsearch!`

Comment: Actually 3: your enter mapping is `*N`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks for the tips on the registers! I was a newb at the time several years back, and probably still am. :) The `*N` trick won't work, because it may move the scroll position, that was the first thing I tried, whereas mine will never move the scroll position (that's what I want).

Comment: I suppose you could use winsaveview/winrestview then

Comment: This looks great — but does the illustrated behavior depend on some other stuff in your vimrc (or require nvim)? If I add this mapping plus bonus 1 and 2 to an empty .vimrc in vim 8.1, use v/shift-v to select something, then press enter, it doesn't search, just remains in visual mode (cursor remains where it is, which is good). If I then disable the bonus 2 mapping, trying the same will go to next line, but still won't search -- just expands my visual selection onto the next line, remaining in visual mode. Un-silencing gives me no errors either; I can't tell if I'm just doing something wrong.

Comment: @BrianCline I don't remember now unfortunately. Hope I didn't miss anything. Here is where it is in my vimrc: https://github.com/trusktr/dotfiles/blob/5d8e1f3b92480f9543b5fca8c089ab0a10522488/home/.vimrc#L1025-L1032

Comment: I liked, then tried, the idea of mapping <enter> (`<cr>`) to be "highlight" -- but eventually I discovered that _interferes_ with opening entries from a `Location` (or `QuickFix`) list just by pressing enter while the cursor is in the list window on the entry you want to open. Without that you have to `:.cc` to open the error under the cursor.  From help: `You can use ":.cc" to jump to the error under the cursor.  Hitting the <Enter> key or double-clicking the mouse on a line has the same effect.`

Answer (score 1):

My [SearchHighlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320) is one of those "visual star" plugins that @D.BenKnoble mentions in his answer; it also has a command that does exactly what you're asking for:

```
:SearchAutoHighlighting selection
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little plugin many years ago, and still use it.

[highlight_word_under_cursor.vim](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/dotfiles/blob/master/.vim/plugin/highlight_word_under_cursor.vim)

Previous versions used `:syntax` but the last iteration uses [`:match`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#match-highlight) so it might bug you if you wanted to use `:match` yourself.

When you land on a word it will highlight other occurrences of that word.  But if you move the cursor and are still on the same word, it will stop the highlighting.  That is supposed to be convenient.

Oh no I am embarrassed by the code now!  Certainly some room for cleanup.  Still it has been working pretty well in my experience.

Comment: No need to be embarrassed! You could switch `:match` for `matchadd()` though