# Highlighting arbitrary text

Tags: highlight

When I'm writing, I often have 2-3 buffers open. My main body of text in the middle, and then supporting materials on the left and right. I often read a paragraph from one of the supporting buffers then switch back to the primary to write for a while before switching back.

I'm trying to figure out how I can highlight a paragraph without selecting it. Is this the `highlight` command or am I barking up the wrong tree? That seems like it's related specifically to syntax highlighting, rather than being able to highlight arbitrary blocks of text.

EDIT: I should clarify that part of why I want to highlight without selecting is that the side windows might be on the same buffer, and 'locked' together rather than independently operated; one can scroll independently but they lock together if you select then switch to another. I may want to look at two different parts of the document and select mode restricts freedom. I tested this, and can't seem to open a new independent buffer on the same file; editing the same file just makes that window join the same buffer.

Comment: have a look at this [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/20077/71)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt i think OP wants to highlight an entire paragraph here

Comment: Edited for clarity

Comment: @Harv can you clarify something for me? It seems like you are having trouble splitting the same buffer (`can't seem to open a new independent buffer on the same file[...]`)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble no - the same buffer splits fine, that's the problem. I want two buffers looking at the same file that operate independently - then visual-select mode would be fine because selecting in one buffer wouldn't affect the other. Or, I need to figure out how to highlight without selecting. The moment I select, the two windows 'lock' together (because they're the same buffer and it's now in visual mode) instead of operating independently.

Comment: @Harv interesting... ill have to go play with that and check it out. I would never have suspected that entering visual mode would tie the windows together in that

Comment: @Harv I guess `vim` stay in `visual mode` if you switch to another window that has the same buffer. Try my answer, it works on `window` rather than `buffer`, just select whatever you want to highlight and `,h` , then go to another window, the highlight is still there, only in one window.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble okay - I just tried to re-produce the issue and failed -- the windows didn't lock together, so I'm not sure why they did before, though I'd like to. Still, when using visual mode select, switching to a different buffer loses the selection, so it no longer stands out from paragraphs above and below it.

Comment: @dedowsdi thank you so much for putting in that much work. I was looking for a simpler answer that would also help me figure out how vim works and why, and frankly that answer is so far over my head that I probably won't learn much from it. I was hoping there was a built in command I just couldn't find.

Answer (score 5):

[:h :highlight](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Ahighlight) is used to define highlight group. What you want is the [:h :match](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%3Amatch) , [:h matchadd()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#matchadd%28%29) families.

This is how I will do it.

### Goal

Highlight arbitary area without staying in visual mode, all wise type should be supported.

### How to do it

The job can be split into three main parts:

1. Select arbitary area:

   There are two ways to select arbitary area in vim.

   - Operator ( bound to `,h` )
   - visual select
2. Highlight it.

   We will use [:h matchadd()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#matchadd%28%29) to do it. We can use [:h /\%l](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%25l) , [:h /\%c](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%25c) to to control the highlight area precisely.
3. Remove highlight area where the cursor is on.

   We will create a map `,hh` for this. We must keep track of every highlighted area and compare current cursor position with them in order for this to work.

### The result

So after finishing it, you can use `,h{motion}` to highlight some area and `,hh` to remove highlight under cursor.

You can also select arbitary area in any visual mode you like and use `,h` to highlight it.

### Build the skeleton

I call a highlight area a `hblock`. `wnd_hblocks` is a list of hblocks per window.

```
nnoremap ,h :set opfunc=AddHighlight<CR>g@
vnoremap ,h :<C-U>call AddHighlight(visualmode(), 1)<CR>
nnoremap ,hh :call <sid>remove_cursor_highlights()<cr>

function AddHighlight(type, ...) abort
  let visual = get(a:000, 0, 0)
  let hblock = s:create_hblock(a:type, visual)
  call s:highlight(hblock)
endfunction

function s:remove_cursor_highlights() abort
  let wnd_hblocks = s:get_wnd_hblocks( bufwinid('') )

  " clear highlight
  call map( copy(wnd_hblocks),
        \ { i,v -> s:contain( v, getcurpos() ) && matchdelete(v.hid) } )

  " clear hblocks
  call filter( wnd_hblocks, { i,v -> !s:contain( v, getcurpos() ) } )
endfunction
```

### The data structure

We will keep track of every hblock, including it's start, end position and selection type.

```
" { winid: [ {hid: , start:  , end:  , wise :  }, ... ] , ...  }
" hid : highlight id return from matchadd
" start : start of cursor pos, same as getcurpos()
" end : ditto
" wise : v, V or "\<c-v>"
let s:hblocks = {}

function s:create_hblock(type, visual) abort
  if a:visual
    let wise = visualmode()
    let start = getpos("'<")
    let end = getpos("'>")
  else
    let wise = a:type ==# 'char' ? 'v' : a:type ==# 'line' ? 'V' : "\<c-v>"
    let start = getpos("'[")
    let end = getpos("']")
  endif

  return {'wise':wise, 'start':start, 'end': end}
endfunction
```

### Rest of the book keeping and highlighting

```
function s:highlight(hblock) abort
  let pattern = s:build_pattern(a:hblock)

  " lazy man's debug register
  let @/ = pattern
  let a:hblock.hid = matchadd('VISUAL', pattern)
  let wnd_hblocks = s:get_wnd_hblocks( bufwinid('') )
  call insert(wnd_hblocks, a:hblock)
endfunction

function s:get_wnd_hblocks(winid)
  if !has_key(s:hblocks, a:winid)
    let s:hblocks[a:winid] = []
  endif
  return s:hblocks[a:winid]
endfunction

function s:contain(hblock, pos)
  let [l0,c0] = a:hblock.start[1:2]
  let [l1,c1] = a:hblock.end[1:2]
  let [l2,c2] = a:pos[1:2]

  if l2 < l0 || l2 > l1
    return 0
  endif

  if a:hblock.wise ==# 'V'
    return 1
  elseif a:hblock.wise ==# "\<c-v>"
    return c2 >= c0 || c2 <= c1
  else

    " not ( cursor in the upper left corner or cursor in the lower right corner)
    return !( l2 == l0 && c2 < c0 || l2 == l1 && c2 > c1 )
  endif
endfunction

function s:build_pattern(hblock)
  let [l0,c0] = a:hblock.start[1:2]
  let [l1,c1] = a:hblock.end[1:2]

  if a:hblock.wise ==# 'V'
    return printf('\v%%>%dl^.*%%<%dl', l0 - 1, l1 + 1)
  elseif a:hblock.wise ==# "\<c-v>"

    " restrict cols on all lines
    return  printf('\v%%>%dl%%>%dc.*%%<%dl%%<%dc', l0 - 1, c0 - 1, l1 + 1, c1 + 1)
  else
    if l0 != l1

      " mid lines | tail of 1st line | head of last line
      return printf('\v%%>%dl^.*%%<%dl|%%%dl%%>%dc.*|%%%dl%%<%dc.*', l0, l1, l0, c0 - 1, l1, c1 + 1)
    else

      " mid of the only line
      return printf('\v%%%dl%%>%dc.*%%%dl%%<%dc', l0, c0 - 1, l1, c1 + 1)
    endif
  endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Whoa. This could be a whole plugin with some clean up and attention to the mapping interface. On that note, `,` is too darn useful (imo) for maps. And the first should really be `nnoremap`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes, it should be `nnoremap` . I only use `,` when i `;` too far, which rarely happens, so I use `,` as the leading character to map all the custom motion and operator, it's much more handier than \ and  _  , as i don't have to move my wrist. A map from `,,` to `,` is also created, in case i really need `,`.